# eGPU support in Mac/macOS

Tags: macos, mac, gpu

I'm wondering whether an external GPU can be (almost) as efficient as the same internal GPU? I need to have a fast computer even when I have a lot of windows open on many virtual desktops and when I run resource intensive application on two 4K displays.

Is macOS able to use an eGPU for its own needs (system animations, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using an external GPU with your Mac (with support for eGPU) can give your computer a performance boost.

Refer to the Apple support article, [Use an external graphics processor with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208544).

> An eGPU can give your Mac additional graphics performance for professional apps, 3D gaming, VR content creation, and more.
>
> eGPUs are supported by any Thunderbolt 3-equipped Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 or later.

For a list of Thunderbolt 3 equipped Macs and to check if your Mac support eGPU, refer to the Apple support article, [Adapters for the Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) or USB-C port on your Mac or iPad Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207443)

These Macs have Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports:

> - iMac Pro
> - iMac models from 2017
> - Mac mini (2018)
> - MacBook Pro models from 2016 or later
>     MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does an eGPU perform in comparison to a GPU? Can an eGPU improve the graphical performances of the system itself?

Comment: @PhilémonBouzy Depends on the technical specifications of the eGPU in comparison to the GPU. Yes, the graphical performance of the system sees a boost.

Comment: Let consider the same GPU (for example a Radeon Vega 56). How does it perform as an eGPU? Is it 80% as fast as the same internal GPU?